# Facing issue in airflow dag skipped dag mail notification

Tags: html, email, notifications, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I wanted to know if there is anything like on_skip_callback to send notification. Using html_email_generator for mail notification.

In my case, for a particular run there are four task and every time run is getting skipped at third task.i have added failure function and is anything needs to be added for skipped mail notification.

```
def failire_callback():
     if task_name is 't1':
         print(" OUTPUT : t1 is failed")
     elif task_name is 't2':
         Print(" OUTPUT : t2 is failed")
     elif task_name is 't3':
         print(" OUTPUT : t3 is failed")
     else 
         Print("OUTPUT : t4 is failed")
     subject = Dag has failed
     message = generate_html_template
     send_email(to=IDs, subject = subject, html_content = message)


default_args = (
      Provide_context = True
      on_failure_callback = failure_callback
      dag = dag
)
```

Comment: this really has very little, if anything, to do with HTML as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get notification for the skipped run also. Is there any default function in airflow for the skipped notification?